# Can we give embos, etching effect to images, text in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash-cs4

I have used Flash 8 long before and want to know if we can apply effects like emboss and etch to text and images. My requirement is :

1. I want to design a interface, where user will add image or text. He will be able to apply effects in same way as we do in photoshop. I don't want to let user control the properties, but just by clicking on the effect icon, the selected effect will be applied to the image or text. The effect can be emboss, etch or texture.
2. I want to save the design so that if user leaves at certain point and later again starts, he should be able to start from the point where he had left. But not sure how to save them.

Does Flash CS4 support those things ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found Flex can handle this.